Why does the picture change to a white area?
I had again a problem while coding my video editor... Here is a simplified code (the variables are in German language, don't wonder and feel free to ask if you don't understand something):
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2
Fenster = Tk()
Fenster.geometry(f"{Fenster.winfo_screenwidth()}x{Fenster.winfo_screenheight()}")
Maximale_Breite = int(Fenster.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.08)
Maximale_Höhe = int(Fenster.winfo_screenheight() * 0.08)
Medien_Importierungen = 0
Medien = Canvas(Fenster, width=Fenster.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.2, height=Fenster.winfo_screenheight(),
                highlightbackground="#dd6800")
Medien.pack(side=LEFT)
Medien_Importieren = Label(Medien, text="Import media")
Medien_Importieren.place(x=int(Fenster.winfo_screenwidth() / 10 - Medien_Importieren.winfo_reqwidth() / 2),
                         y=Fenster.winfo_screenheight() / 20)
def Medien_Hinzufügen(event):
    global Medien_Importierungen, Maximale_Breite, Maximale_Höhe, Tkinter_Bild
    Videopfad = askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Video Files', '*.mp4')])
    if Videopfad:
        Geladenes_Video = cv2.VideoCapture(Videopfad)
        Rückgabe, Einzelbild = Geladenes_Video.read()
        if Einzelbild.shape[0] / Maximale_Höhe > Einzelbild.shape[1] / Maximale_Breite:
            height = Maximale_Höhe
            width = int(Einzelbild.shape[1] * height / Einzelbild.shape[0])
        else:
            width = Maximale_Breite
            height = int(Einzelbild.shape[0] * width / Einzelbild.shape[1])
        Einzelbild = cv2.resize(Einzelbild, (width, height))
        Tkinter_Bild = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(Einzelbild, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)))
        Thumbnail = Label(Medien, image=Tkinter_Bild)
        if Medien_Importierungen % 2 == 0:
            x_position = Fenster.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.01 + Maximale_Breite / 2 - Einzelbild.shape[1] / 2
        else:
            x_position = Fenster.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.11 + Maximale_Breite / 2 - Einzelbild.shape[1] / 2
        y_position = (Fenster.winfo_screenheight() / 10 +
                        (Fenster.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.01 + Maximale_Höhe) * (Medien_Importierungen // 2) +
                        Maximale_Höhe / 2 - Einzelbild.shape[0] / 2)
        Thumbnail.place(x=x_position, y=y_position)
        Medien_Importierungen += 1
Medien_Importieren.bind("<Button-1>", Medien_Hinzufügen)
mainloop()

"Medien_Hinzufügen(x)" is a function which will be executed when a button is clicked to import a video.
Now it shows every time I import a video the first time the first frame of the video, but when I execute the function a second time the picture from the first time will be white and only the first frame from the second video will be showed. That repeats every time I import a video and I don't know how to remedy that problem...
I tried to create the whole label in the if-else-condition but that didn't work either...

Try adding master=Medien inside the ImageTk.PhotoImage(...). If that doesn't work, please provide a [mre] that we should be able to copy/paste and run without any modification

Not related to your question, but I feel like it makes sense to use English variable names when asking a question in an English forum.

@TheLizzard I did that because the "master=Medien" didn't work.., In this example I needed to use cv2 and pil because I couldn't do that without these modules...

@oskar I know but there aren't mutch big German forums and I didn't want to rename all variables in a english language... That's why I also said "feel free to ask" but maybe I will rename the variables in my next question...

It is because same global variable Tkinter_Bild is used for storing the references of the image of new label created, so the previous one will be garbage collected.
One of the ways to keep the reference of the image is using an attribute of the label:
...
Tkinter_Bild = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(Einzelbild, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)))
Thumbnail = Label(Medien, image = Tkinter_Bild)
Thumbnail.image = Tkinter_Bild  # keep the reference using an attribute of the label
...


It worked... I do not quite understand why that is so and my Visual Studio Code also doesn't make the attribute colored but thanks!
